# Создание deb пакета из папки

Tags: debian, install

Есть ли способ создать пакет из папки, полученной в ходе 'make install DESTDIR=somedir'?  Исходники я не сохранил

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22dpkg-deb%22

Comment: Мне это не помогло